# Expected Object, got Array laravel vue pagination

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7

hi guys am sure we all use the laravel vue pagination , and i have used it in the past but getting errors now , cant tell why.

so i have my getresults method

```
getResults(page = 1) {

                axios.get('api/category?page=' + page)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.categories = response.data;
                        
                    });
                
            
                    
                }
```

my data that am returning i.e categories{} (which is an object)

```
data() {
            return {
                
                categories: {},
                // Create a new form instance
                form: new Form({
                    id:'',
                    name: '',
                    active: ''
                }),
      
               
            }
        },
```

and finally the pagination

```
<pagination :data="categories" @pagination-change-page="getResults">
                      <span slot="prev-nav">&lt; Previous</span>
                      <span slot="next-nav"> Next &gt;</span>
</pagination>
```

but am getting error

```
 type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array
```

even its an object , please in need of assistance. thanks

Comment: please log the categories after `this.categories = response.data;`

Comment: you mean this?                                                                                  `axios.get('api/category?page=' + page)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.categories = response.data;

                        console.log(categories)
                        
                    }); `

Comment: what's the output in the console?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim nothing

Comment: oh man, print it as this.categories and not categories

Comment: do `console.log(this.categories) `

Comment: ok just did got `{__ob__: Observer}
categories: Array(4)
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}
length: 4`

Comment: Ya, as you can that's an array

Comment: thatswhy when you pass it to pagination, its showing an error since its expecting an object and you are passing an array

Comment: yes its an array, but my categories is an object i mean `categories: {}` its not `categories: []`@Amaarrockz

Comment: ya initially you have it as {} but as soon as you get the response it then changes to array since the response.data was an array

Comment: @Amaarrockz so how do i change that

Comment: you go to change the structure from the api side

Answer (score 0):

hi guys finally solved the error , i had to restructure the way i was getting my my data from my api

it was this

```
 $categories = Category::latest()->paginate(10);
return response([ 'categories' => CategoryResource::collection($categories), 'message' => 'Retrieved successfully'], 200);
```

i changed it to this

```
return Category::latest()->paginate('10');
```

and that solved the pagination errors . thank you once again